# How can i connect gtx 1050 ti with my vga monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, vga

I saw on the internet that Gtx 1050Ti doesn't have a VGA port . 
So how do i connect it to my VGA monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Which GTX 1050Ti?

A quick search shows at least 19 variants of them, from different manufacturers. Some of them without analog output. If you have one without analog output then you need something to convert from a digital format (DVI-D, DP, HDMI) to analog.

Which output is which is easily identified. Both by looking inside the manual or the manufacturers specification page, or by looking out the outputs on the card.

[image: DVI output picture from wikipedia]
<sup>Souce: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface%20Wikipedia)</sup>

If you have a card which still supports analog out then you can use one of these:
[image: DVI to VGA plug]

If you have a modern card with only digital output then you need something with active electronics in it which actively translated the digital signals to an analog output. Depending on specs these might cost about €30.

Note that there are log of cheaper one. E.g. [Example on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CUPAG3S) (first hit I found while googling) on Amazon. But that one only suppots up to 1920 x 1200.